# $p$-laplacian product rule

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

For the usual Laplacian $\Delta$, we have the product rule
$$\Delta(fg) = f\Delta g + 2\nabla f\cdot\nabla g + g\Delta f.$$
Is there an analogue for the $p$-Laplacian $\Delta_pf = \nabla \cdot (|\nabla f|^{p-2}\nabla f)$ of a similar form where we have a product rule type term at top order plus lower order terms, e.g.
$$\Delta_p(fg) = f\Delta_pg + g\Delta_pf + \text{something else}?$$
Using the product rule for the divergence I get some terms I don't really know how to simplify (the absolute value is unsurprisingly a big problem) to get something of the form above.

Comment: This $p$-laplacian is nonlinear, so not really surprising it doesn't have a nice product rule. In fact, if you think of $f$ and $g$ as physical quantities, none of the terms in that sum in the second equation even have the same units.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out though the units do not agree. I suspected there was a possibility it might not have a product rule but also would not have been surprised if there was linearity at top order and calculations that can be performed.